# A problem in geometry(tangents) to show that $CD= 2AB \cdot (AC^2−AB^2)/(AC^2+AB^2)$

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, tangent-line

Suppose that $O$ is the circumcentre of Triangle $BCD$. Draw the tangent to the circumcircle of $BCD$ at $B$. Extend $CO$ meet this tangent at $A$. Show that

> $$CD= 2AB \,\frac{AC^2−AB^2}{AC^2+AB^2}$$

What I thought was to apply Cevas theorem or Menelaus theorem. But things are not working out.I need some little help. I can't show what I have done as absolutely other than construction I could not do anything.
So I would be obliged if anyone can help.

Comment: Idea: Let CA intersect the circle at Q, then $AB^2=AQ*QC=OA^2-OB^2$

Comment: @Divide1918...can you elaborate your hint in the answer section a bit.  What to do next

Comment: I have no idea what to do next either.

Comment: Hahaha....same with me also

Comment: How about you show what ycou constructed and what you derived from those? Maybe it will give people idea. Just verbally describe your construction, e.g. "construct the angle bisector of XYZ, say it intersects the circle at U" (this by no means has anything to do with your problem at hand, just an example for the general case where you want to verbally describe your construction)

Comment: Can you double check everything in the question and share a diagram? I think this is not correct. Happy to be proven wrong. The whole of RHS will resolve to $2 \, BC \cos D$. There is no guarantee of that being equal to $BC$ unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'll check the question sure.....

Comment: Can you share the part of 2BCcosD part

Comment: will do in sometime

Comment: Thanks....it will help me to identify that the problem is wronv

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: We have:

$AC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2AB\cdot AC cos(\angle BAC)$

$CD^2=AC^2+AD^2-2 AC\cdot AD cos(\angle CAD)$

Now applying Simson and Steward theorems may help you to find the relation.

Answer (score 0):

Showing why this is not necessarily true.

[image]

$\angle OCB = \angle OBC = \theta$

In $\triangle ABC,$

$\displaystyle \frac{AB}{\sin \theta} = \frac{AC}{\sin (90^0 + \theta)} = t$

$AB = t \sin \theta, AC = t \cos \theta$

That gives us

$ \frac {AC^2 − AB^2}{AC^2+AB^2} = \cos 2 \theta$

Now please note $\angle D = \frac{1}{2} \angle BOC = 90^0 - \theta$

Also $AB = R \tan 2 \theta \,$ (as $\angle AOB = 2 \theta \, , \,R$ is the circumradius)

$2 AB \cos 2 \theta = 2R \sin 2 \theta = 4 R \sin \theta \cos \theta = 4 R \sin D \cos D = 2 BC \cos D $

Comment: If you want to show that the expression given in OP's problem statement does not hold, then you have to show $$\frac{CD}{2AB}\ne \cos\left(2\theta\right).$$ You have not done that. Please check the content of your answer/post.

Comment: Please read in the beginning _not necessarily_. Now if you read the question, it is a general case of any triangle. Given $\angle D = 90^0 - \theta, 2 \theta = 180^0 - 2 \angle D$. Will $CD = |2AB \cos (2 \angle D)| \,$ hold for every single triangle or is it a special case? Also why I showed the way I did, there is more context in the comments from OP.

Comment: Sorry for bothering. I did not see the 5 hidden comments.

Comment: @YNK No, you did not bother me at all. Genuine questions and comments are always welcome!